# Separation of concerns in Microservice Architecture

Tags: microservices, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I have some microservices that are plugged on our eCommerce plataform. 
Today, We have our microservices broken as:
 - customer-service
 - order-service
 - delivery-service
 - ...
For e.g., when a new customer join the eCommerce or someone place and order, it makes a webhook for one of our microservices that just get the information and dump to firehose/S3.

My question is: Is it better to maintain the functions that dump data to firehose on separated micro services handling specific subjects (customer, order and so on) or create for example another micro service called "notification-service" that handle all of them?

The other example could be: Each micro service send notification, like email or sms. Or is it better to have a separate micro service that has total responsibility of making notification?

Answer (score 0):

**Microservice** must be created to have a one and only one responsibility , in your case Notification service should be **separate microservice** , which perform the action depending on the events.

Hence you will able to **scale up or down** you notification service when number of notification increases or decreases.